# Stop GUI from freeze during long running process

Tags: c

I have a process that will take a while (maybe 10 minutes) to complete. When I call this from my gtk GUI the window locks up (darkens and prevents user action) after about 10 seconds.
I'd like to stop this from happening, but I'm not sure how. I thought multithreading would be the answer.
I'm new to multithreading, so I'm looking for solution. I'm basically just trying to keep the GUI from locking up so I can update with a progress bar and let the user use a cancel button.

My code to scan tuner frequency:

```
int tuner_get_signal (void)
{
    ..........................

    return tuner.signal >> 13;
}


int tuner_check_station (float freq)
{
    static int a, b;
    static float last;
    int signal;

    signal = tuner_get_signal ();

    if (last == 0.0f)
        last = freq;

    if ((a + b + signal > 8) && (fabsf (freq - last) > 0.25f)) {
        a = b = 0;
        last = freq;
        return 1;
    }
    a = b;
    b = signal;

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that I need to create thread for tuner_get_signal () function

and function to scan

```
typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *dialog;
    GtkWidget *label;
    GtkWidget *progress;
    GList     *stations;
} FreqScanData;


gboolean scan_cb (gpointer data)
{
    static gfloat  freq = FREQ_MIN - 4.0f/20;
    FreqScanData  *fsd = data;

    if (freq > 108) {
        gtk_widget_destroy (fsd->dialog);
        timeout_id = 0;
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (tuner_check_station (freq)) {
        gfloat *f;

        f = g_malloc (sizeof (gfloat));

        *f = freq;
        fsd->stations = g_list_append (fsd->stations, f);
    }

    gtk_progress_bar_set_fraction (GTK_PROGRESS_BAR (fsd->progress),
                   MAX (0, (freq - 87.5) / (108 - 87.5)));

    freq += 1.0/20;
    tuner_set_freq (freq);

    return TRUE;
}
```

call this with:

```
timeout_id = g_timeout_add (50, (GSourceFunc)scan_cb, (gpointer)&data);
```

Comment: have your tried running the program in background ?

Comment: What is the problem you have? What is the error your get, what works, what does not work? The underlying idea of using a different thread is good, and (if done correctly) should solve your problem.

Comment: You see, there's this thing called multithreading.

Comment: Run a separate *process* (not thread) for the long task. The problem with threads is that they cannot be stopped at will. They need to be cancelled at well-defined cancellation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution to your problem is multithreading (backgrounding of the computation). It is a good idea to use Gtk+ functionality for that as well (as you show in your example solution).

However if your program is rather simple and you don't want to make it complicated (esp. with communication of results, cancellation etc.), you can also interrupt your scanning routine frequently to process Gtk+ events. See the documentation of events_pending():
http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/gtk/gtk-General.html#gtk-events-pending

Obviously, the overall performance of the multithreading solution is better especially as nowadays most computers come with several CPU cores.